# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined (reading 'green')

Tags: javascript

```js
const mainebutton = document.querySelector("button");
const body = document.body;

function randomcolorgenerator() {
  const red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  console.log(red, green, blue);
  const randomcolor = "rgb ${red},${green},${blue}";
  return randomcolor;
}
mainebutton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const randomcolor = randomcolorgenerator();
  console.log(randomcolor);
});
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined (reading 'green')

Comment: Other than `"rgb ${red},${green},${blue}"` not working (needs backticks (`) instead of quotes), I don't see where that error would be thrown

Comment: the code is running without any error. would you please mention where are you injecting the script?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Explain your problem and ask a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add a '`DOMContentLoaded`' event listener to wait for your content to load before accessing them

And adding what @Luca has mentioned, this should be a template string:

"rgb ${red},${green},${blue}" should be enclosed in `` not ""

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    const mainebutton = document.querySelector("button");
    const body = document.body;
    function randomcolorgenerator() {
        const red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        const green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        const blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);console.log(red, green, blue);
        const randomcolor = `rgb ${red},${green},${blue}`;
        return randomcolor;
    }
    mainebutton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const randomcolor = randomcolorgenerator();
        console.log(randomcolor);
    });
})
```

```html
<button>SHOW ME A COLOR</button>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the OPs error? It seems like the code would have worked without the DOMContentLoaded listener (it does on here)